# NavigationStack not showing master-detail view on iPad in landscape

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I've the following code which displays a master-detail view on iPad when in landscape.
However, when I use NavigationStack it collapses views as on iPhone.
What am I missing here?
Or how to achieve this another way?

```
struct OwnersView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: OwnersVM
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                ForEach(vm.owners) { owner in
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        
                        Text(owner.name)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        HStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("\(owner.name) gold piece list")) {
                                Image("jewelry-filled")
                            }
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("\(owner.name) cash list")) {
                                Image("cash-filled")
                            }
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("\(owner.name) some other list")) {
                                Image("zakah-filled")
                                
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Owners")
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `NavigationSplitView` instead.